# Add Hover affect to specific parts of an image

Tags: javascript, hover, jpeg

Sorry in advance if this is the wrong board to post in. If it is could someone kindly redirect me to the proper website?

Hi all, I'm trying to add a hover affect that will highlight each building using **[THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uhm0.jpg)**
image. There're multiple buildings so I need to split them up. Is there a way to set a border each building, and know which building I'm hovering over? For example if I hovered over the building to the bottom it would display information related to that building.

Are there any tools that could make this a lot simpler to do?

Comment: You can use image map

Comment: thankyou im looking into this right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this:

The good ol' [`<map>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map), as said in a comment, would be one. Positioning multiple images over each other would be another one.

Looking at the picture **the method I'd recommend** would be to [create an SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG). The image looks like it's coming from a 3D tool. Most probably you can export the image as an SVG and display that SVG on your webpage. The benefits of doing it this way is:

- The image size will be small. Most probably smaller than the corresponding picture as pixel based (jpeg/png/etc).
- The image will scale without loss of quality.
- Most important in this case: You can easily make each building it's own element, meaning that you can have it to react on hover, clicks, etc.

I recommend reading an introduction to SVG, such as:

- http://tonyfreed.com/blog/introduction-to-svg
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Introduction

If you want to use your JPEG image (and not go for the SVG route) you can still use SVG to be able to create "hover-zones". It would look something like this:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 800 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
    <image width="800" height="500" xlink:href="yourImage.jpg" />
    <polygon id="building1" points="200,10 250,190 160,210" width="800" height="500" />
</svg>
```

And then you can have your JS code react to hover on `#building1`. Here's a tutorial on this technique: http://thenewcode.com/760/Create-A-Responsive-Imagemap-With-SVG

Comment: thankyou so much, This was stopping me from continuing with my work !!